# Combine multiple lines starting with same phrase into one

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, toml

I'm writing a Bash script to convert Arch Linux packages into a format for a package manager I'm writing, and I have to convert some metadata files into file format `.toml`. Previously, I've been using `sed`, but I just need something I can implement into a Bash script. The conversion should look like shown below.

Input:

```
... other stuff ...
depends = "some-dependency"
depends = "another-dependency"
depends = "yet-another-dependency"
```

Output:

```
... other stuff already converted ...
depends = [ "some-dependency", "another-dependency", "yet-another-dependency" ]
```

Comment: With GNU awk: `awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\"[^\"]*\""; RS=""; OFS=", "} {$1=$1; print "depends = [ " $0 " ]"}' file`?

Comment: It kinda works, but it puts all of the input fields in instead of only `depends` lines. I should've mentioned that the input has more than just `depends`. I will try to edit it, but I don't really know awk that well.

Comment: Welcome, you say *"I've been using sed, but I just need something I can implement into a bash script"*. I'm not sure I understand, why can't you use `sed` inside a bash script?

Comment: What's the "other stuff" that you do not mention?

Comment: Regarding `should've mentioned that the input has more than just depends` - yes but, more importantly, you should have included lines with more than `depends` in the sample input/output you provided to demonstrate your requirements and for us to test a potential solution with.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F' = ' '
    $1 == "depends" {
        printf "%s %s", (flag!=1 ? "depends = [" : ","), $2
        flag=1
        next
    }
    flag {
        print " ]"
        flag=0
    }
    { print }
    END {
        if (flag) print " ]"
    }
' file
```

Input:

```
... other stuff ...
depends = "some-dependency"
depends = "another-dependency"
depends = "yet-another-dependency"
... more stuff ...
depends = "next-dependency"
depends = "and-another-dependency"
```

Output:

```
... other stuff ...
depends = [ "some-dependency", "another-dependency", "yet-another-dependency" ]
... more stuff ...
depends = [ "next-dependency", "and-another-dependency" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Excluding "...other stuff.." section from the input file, you can use this code:

```
$ awk -F"=" 'NR==1{printf $1 " = [" } {printf $2 ","};END{print""}' infile | sed 's/.$/\]/'

depends  = [ "some-dependency", "another-dependency", "yet-another-dependency"]
```